# adding content to dynamic fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```
 $.post('ajax.php', { callback: 'send_mail', name: $("#name").val() },
            function(data){
                if(data.request == 'success'){
                            $.fancybox(data.name);  


                }else{

                    alert('error');

                }
            }, 'json');
```

here is my ajax call in my fancybox and while it does work, it is a default fancybox.
The original fancy box has these options

```
$('#login_page').fancybox({ 
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'overlayOpacity': 0.1,
        'showCloseButton'   : false

    });
```

My question is, how do I place my returned value inside the fancy box and set the options?

EDIT:

ah I figured it out. There is an advanced option for content:

Comment: Answer your own question with your solution, because this question needs a solution. Or just delete this question.

Answer (score 7):

There is an option called content that allows you to input html.

```
"content" : "<p>sfsdfsdf</p>",
```